# How to generate separate page urls?

Tags: php

I have a small system. Users can login to see the work records. That page URL is something like this

```
domain.com/view_works.php
```

but my client needs separate page URLs for each and every user. Something like this:

If user name is `user1`

```
domain.com/user1_works.php
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about `domain.com/user1/works.php` -- you can achieve that with an `.htaccess` rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Your post has a significant weakness in that an ideal answer would require knowing a lot of specifics about your situation. However, I can tell by the information that you've given that you haven't been exposed to a lot of relevant concepts that I can expand on to help you find a good solution for yourself.

Other answers here are suggesting using a rewrite rule. I don't recommend that. That is probably a lazy/hacky solution and not an ideal practice. It's often recommended that you route all requests to one php file and have your php logic route the request to where it belongs. That being, the first step is the create or use your existing php system to route the request to a specific handler for users.

RESTful api's suggest a lot about what a nice, uniform, and intuitive uri should look like. While we're not trying to create an api here...it's worth considering the principles REST teaches us. I wouldn't use verbs in your uri. Typing in a url and going to that page implies that the user intends to view something, therefore `domain.com/view_works.php` makes a lot more sense as `domain.com/works` or `domain.com/someUserName/works`

The specific implentation REALLY depends on many factors. Depending on what `domain.com` is/contains, something like `domain.com/users/someUserName/works` might be the better choice. What you might do from there is have your main `index.php` (the file which all requests are routed to) parse the uri so that you know you need to send the request to a `users` controller, which can select `someUserName` and display that user's `works`.

As I said, there are plenty of options, but at least simply using `preg_match` to parse the url into pieces and routing anything with `/users/` to `users.php` and having it work out who/what to display would be a better approach than accessing files directly like `view_works.php`, using verbs in the uri with ugly file extensions at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess you can put this for example:

`RewriteRule ^user([0-9]*)/works$ /view_works.php?userid=$1 [L]`

That will result in `yoursite.com/user123/works` go to `view_works.php?userid=123`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache as the web server, you can use it's [rewrite engine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve this functionality. With it you can internally redirect any URL you wish (defined with a regex expression) to any PHP script and pass any part of the regex as a parameter of the script.

For example, you could rewrite so that the URL:

```
domain.com/user1_works.php
```

internally redirects to:

```
domain.com/works_user_handler.php?user=user1
```