# Fast .htaccess fix?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How would I modify my .htaccess to send http://rpgs.biz/rpg-test to just http://rpgs.biz/test

Here's my current .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

rewriterule ^rpg-([^&]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

**I greatly appreciate any help, thanks!**

Comment: See my posts here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034636/understanding-of-custom-urls/20034826#20034826 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961123/how-to-generate-seperate-page-urls/19961518#19961518. They should help give you some direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current htaccess is taking rpg-(something) and passing the "something" into index.php, you'll need to change *that* as well. Maybe something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^rpg-([^/]+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# this is your old rule, modified
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!
Any ideas how to take this a step forward and create a subdomain instead? for example "rpgs.biz/test to test.rpgs.biz"

Comment: @SativaDiva if you are mapping everything to `index.php?name=` then you don't need to deal with any `/test` path. Match against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` and use `%1` to backreference the match

Comment: I feel like I'm starting to get the hang of it but the last sentence confused me, could you edit the code above with an example of what that would look like? I really appreciate the help so far, you've really made my week! :)

Comment: Try doing  a search for "htaccess subdomain"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Redirect 301 /rpg-test http://rpgs.biz/test
```

But if you need to retain the files after /rpg-test, such as /rpg-test/cart.php or something, then you'd do:

```
RewriteRule ^rpg-test/?(.*) http://rpgs.biz/test/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple redirect, it's easy:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^rpg-([^&]+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sidebar: If it's a live site, you should always add the 301 in there so that you don't lose any search engine page ranking.

Comment: Very close, but let's say rpg-"test" is generated from ^rpg-([^&]+)$, simply removing rpg- so it's just ^([^&]+)$ didn't work.

Comment: @SativaDiva In this case, you need to change your RewriteRule, so you are redirected from rpg-(whatever) to /whatever. See the update.