# htaccess rewriterule for directory structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess rewrite problem. We have requests entering with multiple subdirectories and an .html file
    for example       `dir1/file.html`
    or                `dir1/dir2/file.html`
    or                `dir1/dir2/dir3/file.html`
    or                `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.html`

what we eventually need is a rewrite rule to

```
index.html?dir1=$1&dir2=$2&dir3=$3&dir4=$4&file=$5
```

(where `dir2` to `dir5` would be empty if path is too short)

Is there any way to do that directly in the .htaccess file, or is it necessary to handle it in php?

Comment: I recommend routing with php rather than htaccess. There are a lot of advantages...here's a previous answer of mine that might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961123/how-to-generate-seperate-page-urls/19961518#19961518

Comment: Oops, that was the wrong link! The best thing to do would probably be to use a framework that handles routing, but here's that link for a basic demonstration with php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034636/understanding-of-custom-urls/20034826#20034826

Comment: thanks m59, this was my backup plan, will consider it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will see if I can test this out, but this *should* work for the problem as your question states it:

```
RewriteRule     ^/([a-z0-9]+)/?([^/]*)$       /index.php?dir1=$1&$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule     ^/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$    /index.php?dir1=$1&dir2=$2&dir3=$3&dir4=$4 [L]
RewriteRule     ^/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$    /index.php?dir1=$1&dir2=$2&dir3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule     ^/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$    /index.php?dir1=$1&dir2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule     ^/([a-z0-9]+)/?$    /index.php?dir1=$1 [L]
```

I *emphasize* should because only you can really say what your site structure is & how this cascading ruleset would affect your application.

The regex used is fairly simple:

```
([a-z0-9]+)
```

That captures any directory name with letters & characters.  If you want to capture—let’s say—underscores and dashes on top of that, it would change to something like:

```
([a-z0-9_-]+)
```

The first rewrite rule I have set—`^/([a-z0-9]+)/?([^/]*)$`—is to capture anything that comes after `dir1` just in case there’s data to capture that is not a strict directory structure. You can comment that out if you wish.  Just added it since that’s how I like to handle situations that need URL parsing like this.

Also, have you considered adding this to the rewrite rule? Perhaps at the top before the rules cascade in?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: that's pretty much what i have and works with directories, but as soon as i add the html file as additional parameter i mess up... (sorry, i don't have my htaccess file here to post)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you this

```
http://domain/dir1-dir2-dir3-dir4-dir5-file.html
```

rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.+)-(.+) $1/$2 [N]
```

you can even make it dynamic by adding these

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

this is much cleaner.

UPDATE:

well I didn't mean you use the second part but anyways I explain what I meant, it's not wrong that people use QUERY STRING for passing path in URL but it's important how you do that like in this URL

```
http://domain/index.php?route=dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file.html
```

as you can see you will grab the path easily with just one GET variable and even handling of this in RewriteRule is much easier like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

which will let you to have a URL like this

```
http://domain/dir1/dir2/dir3/.../file.html
```

and with any reason you may change those slash to hyphen or other acceptable chars which become like this

```
http://domain/dir1-dir2-dir3-dir4-dir5-dir6-dir7-file.html
```

and as I said it's more easier to pass the current QUERY_STRING which will look like this

```
http://domain/dir1-dir2-file.html?q=extra_query_value
```

and result in PHP if you dump $_GET will be:

```
q => 'extra_query_value'
route => 'dir1/dir2/file.html'
```

and finally in PHP you may easily explode them to have all folders' name by individual variable.

Comment: replace hyphens in that string with splash, this works even more deeper, such as 'dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7' more or less

Comment: I just explained why he has not use QUERY STRING like that, this is his choice, even he already said he can handle it in php if there would be an option.